# Inside a QWidget, Qwt plot is there then if i am trying to resize widget simultaneously plot should resize. how to apply resizeevent to QWidget

Tags: qt

I have applied `resizeEvent` to a `QWidget`. I am trying to resize the widget inside another widget. I have a QWT plot that should also resize.

I have applied `resizeEvent` to the `QWidget` and resized to the plot:

```cpp
void SampleWidget:: resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    int diffofWidth = event->size().width() - event->oldSize().width();     
    int diffofHeight = event->size().height() - event->oldSize().height();
    QSize size = plot->size();
    if ((event->oldSize().width() >= 0) && (event->oldSize().height() >= 0))
    {
        if (event->size().width() <= this->minimumWidth() && event->size().height() <= this->minimumHeight())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            plot->resize(size.width() + diffofWidth, size.height() + diffofHeight);
            plot->replot();
        }
    }
}
```

The widget is able to resize, but after resizing many times, the plot is only displayed partially in the widget. I am not able to see whole content in the widget. What's going on here?

Comment: For me it is completely unclear what are you asking. My best guess would be to make any child of `SampleWidget` part of the `SampleWidget`'s layout.

Comment: inside a SampleWidget, qwt plot is there( child of SampleWidget). when i am trying to resize the SampleWidget, inside child (qwt plot) should resize. But, after implementing resizeEvent method output is displaying like plot is displaying beyond the size of SampleWidget. So, that i am not able to see complete plot inside a SampleWidget.

Comment: Please, prepare a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to let us have a chance to find the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking why your widget isn't resizing properly, you likely have minimum sizes set within the layouts. Be sure that your minimum size of the parent is greater than or equal to the sum of it's children, that could cause the child elements to be partially hidden.

Also, check `sizehint` and the `minimum size` set for each object, increase them as needed.